# How to disable certain items in ListView based on QAbstractListModel?

Tags: qt5, qtquick2, qabstractlistmodel

I have a `QAbstractListModel` C++ model class and a QtQuick2 `ListView`.

For testing purposes I also create a QtWidgets `QListView` and attach to the same model for comparison.

I want to tell the view which items should be disabled using a overridden `QAbstractListModel::flags()` like in this example:

```
Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    Qt::ItemFlags f = QAbstractListModel::flags(index);
    if(index.isValid())
    {
        f |= Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable;

        if(index.row() % 3 == 2)
            f &= ~Qt::ItemIsEnabled;
    }
    return f;
}
```

[Complete model class here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45194359)

Sadly the QtQuick2 ListVie completely ignores this flag while the QListView does not:

[image: Left: QtWidgets QListView, Right: QtQuick2 ListView]

I want item2 and item5 to be also disabled in QtQuick2. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

If you use CheckDelegate you should tune it via the delegate properties:

```
   delegate: CheckDelegate {
        text: model.display
        checked: model.checkState
        enabled: <here is your predicate, for example "index % 2" for each odd item>
    }
```

It is because QML uses different approach to visualize data in opposite to QWidgets.

Comment: I really want to control that from C++, I just implemeted it for the example using this calculation. Later my model will look into a database column. I think I can't avoid another custom Role in `::data()` that returns a bool for enabled, right?

Comment: @DanielBrunner if your predicate depends on model data, so the right way is to share this data as model role and use it to build presentation logic inside your QML, not in your model.

Comment: Does Qml use the flags then at all? I mean it ignored the `ItemIsUserCheckable` and `ItemIsEnabled`. It looks like only widget views follow them!

Comment: @DanielBrunner as I wrote earlier QML uses delegate to get representation of model.

Comment: If you want to control the QML view with the C++ model, I would try modifying the data() menthod of the AbstractListModel since that function is the one that is in charge of what will be displayed in the view. You can also try making a copy of the data structure that contains the model and modify the copy?